# array where each even index powered by 2, odd index powered by 3

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new here. I have this code where each array's element is powered by 3 along the way to result something like 3pow0, 3pow1, 3pow2, 3pow3 etc...:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    const int n = 10;
    int pwr[n];
    pwr[0] = 1;
    int k = 1;
    printf("%d ", pwr[0]);

    while(k < n){
        pwr[k] = pwr[k - 1] * 3;
        printf(" %d ", pwr[k]);
        k++;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I need to make each odd index in array to be powered by 3, and each even index to become powered by 2.

I tried to use something like `while(k < n && k % 2 == 1)` and also played with "for" and "if-else". Can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Note: you are multiplying when you say "power"

Comment: to be precise because i think its not clear what i want. i need each odd index element to be like 3pow0, 3pow1... 3pow4 etc. and each even index to be like 2pow0, 2pow1... 2pow5 etc...

Comment: Guessing, so not an official answer.  pow[0] = pow[1] = 1; for ( k = 2; k < n; k+= 2 ) { k[n] = k[n-2] * 2; k[n+1] = k[n-1] * 3; } // debugging is left as an exorcise to the student. Like the answer and I can make it official.

Comment: I assume, the purpose of that task is to use modulo operator.

Comment: Your code and your question do not match. Please provide a sample set of values you want to get. Your code does not use any power of a number.

Comment: Yes I’m sorry it’s NOT the powered by 2 and powered by 3 question. I want to get 1 1 2 3 4 9 8 27 16 81 32 243 64 729 128 etc. sorry for wrong Q title

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
    pwr[k] = pwr[k - 1] * ((k%2)+2);
```

If `k` is odd, `k%2` is 1 and so it will multiply with 3.

Comment: I like this solution, but looks like i need smth like:
[0] = 1, [1] is odd = 3pow0, [2] is even = 2pow0, [3] is odd = 3pow1, [4] is even = 2pow1, [5] is odd = 3pow2 etc... maybe i understood my task wrong, but feels like it wants from me smth like this. Sorry that can't show how this task sounds, because it's not originally written in english. anyway is it possible to make smth like what i mentioned in this comment? sorry for bothering with studying questions =/

Comment: i like this answer very much it's just my english was wrong. btw my code during my tries was:

    while(k < n){
        if (k % 2 == 0){
            pwr[k] = pwr[k - 1] * 2;
            printf("%d ", pwr[k]);
            k++;
        }
        else {pwr[k] = pwr[k - 1] * 3;
            printf("%d ", pwr[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }

which do the same as your's compact example "pwr[k] = pwr[k - 1] * ((k%2) + 2); so your answer is very elegant and useful anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode, I think what you want is

```
for(i in some range of values) {
    if(i is even) {
        array[i] = i * i;
    } else {
        array[i] = i * i * i;
    }
}
```

I'll let you translate this into proper C.